# I have a problem says import dart:html in android studio and i didn't add any thing to app i just doing a hot reload?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have a problem says import dart:html in android studio and i didn't add any thing to app i just doing a hot reload?[this is the error of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhM9s.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select suppose Text from the drop down list, make sure you have selected the one which has "material.dart" written at the right side of that "Text". The problem you are facing is mainly because, by mistake, you chose " Text" with "html.dart" written at the right side. So the dart file automatically generates a html.dart package which is not defined anywhere before.